# Telerik Office 2010 Blue Theme for WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, telerik

Does anybody know if they offer the Office 2010 Blue Theme for WPF Telerik Controls? I have searched, and cant really find any answers. When I try to apply the "Office_Blue" theme in my XAML, it is the Office 2007 Blue Theme.

Answer (score 0):

There are only seven themes offered by Telerik for their controls.  They do not offer a differentiation between Office 2007 and 2010 versions for their Office themes.  Here is a list of their themes:
http://www.telerik.com/help/wpf/common-styling-apperance-setting-theme-wpf.html